# Combining document ready scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a simple show-hide script on various IDs. The issue is as it stands right now each is a seperate JS that calls the document ready function via jQuery.

Is there a way to combine this into one more flexible script or at least into one script in some form or another. Thank you so much for your time in advance!

Below is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#loadDummy7").hover(

    function () {
        $("#dummy7").show();
    }, function () {
        $("#dummy7").hide();
    });
}); 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#loadDummy8").hover(
    function () {
        $("#dummy8").show();
    }, function () {
        $("#dummy8").hide();
    });
});    
</script>
```

Comment: Why is this a problem? It'll work fine with multiple ready() blocks.

Comment: Or just combine into one ready() block.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine it into a single script like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("[id^='loadDummy']").hover(function() {
    $("#" + this.id.replace('loadD', 'd')).toggle();
  });
});
```

This uses the [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to get all `id="loadDummyXXX"` controls and finds the element to toggle with the corresponding `dummyXXX` ID.  An easier way would be to use classes and find it relatively, for example if your markup was like this:

```
<div class="dummyWrapper">
  Stuff
  <div class="dummy" style="display: none;"> More Stuff</div>
</div>
```

You could do it like this, much cleaner:

```
$(function(){
  $(".dummyWrapper").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".dummy").toggle();
  });
});
```